# get values of nonZero elements of a 2-dim cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get values of nonZero elements of a 2-dim cv::Mat and put the result on a cv::Mat. How I can do this ? I used following code to get the index of nonZero elements :

```
cv::vector<cv::Vec2i> nonzero ;
cv::findNonZero(mask,nonzero);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`copyTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=copyto#mat-copyto). It allows you to specify a mask, where zeros indicate pixels you want to ignore, and any non-zero pixels will be included. You don't even need to find the pixel locations.

```
Mat dst;
src.copyTo(dst, src);
```

Where `src` has the values you want and zeros where you want to ignore it, and `dst` is where you place the non-zero values.

Comment: I edited my code : mask = map>= threshold ;
    cv::Mat nonzero ;
    map.copyTo(nonzero,mask); but the nonzero mat size is equal to map. I want a matrix that just included the nonzero element

Comment: You want a *matrix* or a *vector* with all the values? Because what would the shape of the matrix be? What do you actually plan to do with these values?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at bellow link:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/161764/get-values-of-nonzero-elements-of-a-2-dim-cvmat/